# How to keep image aligned to the right of the window regardless of how the window is resized?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The problem is the image is not fixed to the right side of the screen, so when I resize the screen it the image goes off screen, e.g.:

[image]

In that example we should see an image of a full phone.

I have the following Grid layout defined:

```
<Grid Background="White" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="166" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="473" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="330" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- some irrelevant stuff removed -->

    <Canvas Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgLogo" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Height="45" Margin="30,135,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="99" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-7" />
        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/MobileBrandingSample.png" Height="634" Width="316" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,14,0,0" Name="imgPhone" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
        <Label Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="127" Content="" Height="20" Name="lblCompanyName" Width="169" FontSize="15" Padding="0,0,0,0" />

        <Label Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="150" Height="20" Name="lblPhoneNumber" Width="160" FontSize="12" Padding="0,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Name="tbPhoneNumberLabel" Text="" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="#35B6E5" Width="160"></TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

With this, `imgPhone` is right aligned, but when I resize the window `imgPhone` goes off screen. What do I need to keep `imgPhone` docked to the right of the screen, regardless of how the window is resized?

Comment: Do you really need to use Canvas?

Comment: I need to keep imgLogo & the labels absolutely positioned over imgPhone. This works with Canvas. If there's another, better way, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: can you post an image of the final result you pretend? I may be wrong, but if you use a Grid and set imgPhone in Grid.Row=0, Grid.Column=0 and then set the labels in the same (Grid.row=0, grid.column=0), they will overlap the image!

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot of the problem. In it you see the labels and imgLogo populated

Comment: do you want the phone under the labels and buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the Canvas, use a Dockpanel with a Grid inside it, dock the whole lot right and absolute sizing in the grid will keep things where you want them relative to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this....and got a solution...maybe not exactly what you want but I think you can work out the few adjustments needed.

```
<Grid Background="White" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="company name"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Phone number"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Logo name"></TextBlock>
    <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Upgrade branding"></Button>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Load logo"></Button>

    <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="C:\Users\somonteiro\Desktop\Montagens\somonteiro.jpg"></Image>

</Grid>
```